# Redirect to a Custom 404 Page When the URL ends with Dot

Tags: iis, web-config, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

In my `web.config` file, I putted this rule to redirect to a custom 404 page and it works fine for URLs that really doesn't exists.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Auto" errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/CustomErrors.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

My problem is for URLs that ends with a `Point(.)` character. For Example

```
http://192.168.1.151/login.
```

Or

```
http://192.168.1.151/login....
```

That causes the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.

[image: 404 error]

StackOverFlow handled this problem fine:
[404 page in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/x...)

Any advice could be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/456803/trailing-dots-in-url-result-in-empty-404-page-on-iis

Comment: @PeterHahndorf thank you, I wrote an answer in that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this attribute in the httpRuntime section helped:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime ... relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" .../>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the URL in an HTTP request is required to be a valid Windows file path.

More information about [relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.relaxedurltofilesystemmapping(v=vs.110).aspx)